# Detect when the currently selected element is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a form with a number of fields on it. I need to be able to tell when the user has selected a different field.

Currently, I've been using the following:

```
 $(document).on('focus click', function () {
        //...
    });
```

However this only works for clicking fields. If I tab through the fields, I'm not able to detect any changes.

I had thought .on('focus') would handle tabbing through fields, but I was apparently wrong. Is there a simpler way of detecting focus change across a full page, rather than individual elements?

Comment: Try replacing `$(document).on('focus click', function () {` with `$("input").on('focus', function () {`...

Comment: As Lal mentions, you are putting a click/focus listener on the document, not the inputs

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery to select the *input* elements *not* the `document`

```
$('input').on('focus', function () { //... });
```

Tabbing through should work.